# How to update all live data the same time?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I want to update my live data(s) in my ViewModel when the app detects the user's filters changed on a drawer layout close listener. I have created an update all live data method in my ViewModel, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class ReleasesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private HashMap<String, MutableLiveData<List<_Release>>> upcomingReleasesListMap = new HashMap<>();
    private ReleasesRepository releasesRepository;
    private ArrayList<Integer> platforms;
    private ArrayList<Integer> platformsCopy;
    private String region;

    public ReleasesViewModel() {
        upcomingReleasesListMap = new HashMap<>();
        // Shared to all fragments : User settings region & platforms
        region = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_REGION, "North America");
        Set<String> defaultPlatformsSet = new HashSet<>();
        platforms = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.PLATFORM_IDS);
        if (platformsCopy == null) {
            // Set only once [past copy of platforms]
            platformsCopy = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.PLATFORM_IDS);
        }
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> getUpcomingReleases(String filter) {
        // ReleasesRepository takes a different monthly filter
        if (upcomingReleasesListMap.get(filter) == null) {
            // we don't have a mapping for this filter so create one in the map
            MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> releases = new MutableLiveData<>();
            upcomingReleasesListMap.put(filter, releases);
            // also call this method to update the LiveData
            loadReleases(filter);
        } else if (upcomingReleasesListMap.containsKey(filter)) {
            // Double check if it isn't null, just in case
            if (upcomingReleasesListMap.get(filter) == null || isPlatformsUpdated()) {
                // if null; try again to update the live data or if platforms filter changed
                loadReleases(filter);
            } // else just don't do anything, the list is already in the Map
        }

        return upcomingReleasesListMap.get(filter);
    }

    private void loadReleases(final String filter) {
        releasesRepository = new ReleasesRepository(region, filter, platforms);
        releasesRepository.addListener(new FirebaseDatabaseRepository.FirebaseDatabaseRepositoryCallback<_Release>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<_Release> result) {
                // sort by release date
                if (platforms.size() > 1) {
                    // Will only sort for multiple platforms filter
                    Collections.sort(result);
                }
                // just use the previous created LiveData, this time with the data we got
                MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> releases = upcomingReleasesListMap.get(filter);
                releases.setValue(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> releases = upcomingReleasesListMap.get(filter);
                releases.setValue(null);
            }
        });
    }

    // Detects when user added/removed platform to update lists based on platforms
    private boolean isPlatformsUpdated() {
        Collections.sort(platforms);
        Collections.sort(platformsCopy);
        if (platforms.equals(platformsCopy)) {
            // nothing new added since past update
            return false;
        }
        // something new added or removed, change
        platformsCopy = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.PLATFORM_IDS);
        return true;
    }

    public void updateAllReleasesList() {
        // update all releases live data lists
        for (String filter : upcomingReleasesListMap.keySet()) {
            loadReleases(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

The `updateAllReleasesList` is the method I created to update all my livedata lists, but in calling this method it will call the `loadReleases` method again and inside this method, it will skip the entire listener `addListener` code for some reason.

In my fragments where I listen to the data changes I have this following simple observer:

```
mReleasesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
    mReleasesViewModel.getUpcomingReleases(filter).observe(this, new Observer<List<_Release>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<_Release> releases) {
            // whenever the list is changed
            if (releases != null) {
                mUpcomingGamesAdapter.setData(releases);
                mUpcomingGamesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mDatabaseLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

And when I call my update all method in my ViewModel on drawer close, the code inside the observer in my fragment gets called (the list returned is empty), but I want it to call `getUpcomingReleases` to update everything.. Any ideas on how to update all my current livedatas at the same time and reflect it on the UI?

Comment: Properly observed and set LiveData should automatically be updated across the entire activity (including the fragments that are hosted within it), from what I understand. 

Is the problem that the list returned to the fragment is empty and supposed to contain some items? Or is the problem that the Firebase listener is skipped? Or both? Firebase listener might be skipped because the viewmodel isn't garbage collected, just updated and your code isn't removing the first listener properly.

Comment: The list is empty because the Firebase listener is skipped, I think. Ok I need to remove the listener first?

Comment: Did you log all the methods in the class first to see what's actually being called when you close the drawer? (To verify what is actually being run when you close the nav.) This seems like an odd implementation though, but I'm not that familiar with Firebase yet though.

Comment: What seems like an odd implementation?

Comment: The extra methods in your ViewModel, but I've only used ViewModels with DAOs for DBs. I implement my VMs with only the constructor and one simple LiveData get method. I use a class that extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory and takes in the database to create and return only one instance of the VM. I don't know if a firebase database would behave the same way in this type of implementation though. Either way, are you sure `loadReleases()` is called and neither `onSuccess()` or `onError()` returns once you close the nav drawer with log statements?